# Difference between magento full package installation and using Composer for Magento?

Tags: php, linux, magento, ubuntu, magento-2.0

Please anyone explain me the difference between magento full package installation and using Composer for Magento.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

Which is best composer magento or full package installation. And how to choose for me to select.

Answer (score 3):

magento full package installation means with sample data installation and using Composer is command line installation.

Comment: Dumb question maybe but, where do you install Composer: locally or on the server? I want something easy to upgrade Magento and install modules and they mention Composer all the time.